# How to tell Prisma that the autogenerated field shouldn't be included in Create/Update operations

Tags: typescript, prisma

I hope all is well.

This is probably a recurring question but somehow I haven't found it yet.

I've got a model like the following:

```
model Users {
  id        Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  firstName String     @db.VarChar(50)
  lastName  String     @db.VarChar(50)
  email     String     @unique @db.VarChar(100)
...
}
```

When generating the Prisma client for this model, the expected data for `prisma.users.create()` included the `id` field, despite it being autogenerated. Same thing for the update method.

How do I specify that these fields aren't supposed to be managed by us, but the database?

TIA

Comment: the generated `id` field should be optional. maybe you're doing something wrong. just restart your typescript server after generating the prisma client. (you can do it by typing `restart ts server` in the vscode pallete).

Comment: Oh I understand why. I've been using the Users type instead of using the UsersCreateInput type.